# JWT security in Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring Boot application that is very close to working except for the most important part.  Essentially the setup four microservices (there are several others, but four for purposes of this question).

- service registry: a Eureka service registry
- gateway: a Zuul Gateway service through which all other services communicate,
- security: a simple service that has a login web page and implements JWT authentication
- web: a simple web application that displays content that the user must be authorized to see

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a security configuration that checks for a valid jwt token, and if not found, then forward to a custom login page.

This is hard to explain, so I'll make up some port numbers illustrate.  We can forget about the service registry port.

- gateway: 8080
- security: 8081
- security via gateway: http://localhost:8080/security
- web: 8082
- Web via gateway: http://localhost:8080/web

I can show the login page through the gateway with: http://localhost:8080/security/login and it looks good.  But when I try to a page in the web microservice: http://localhost:8080/web/page, I expect to be forwarded to http://localhost:8080/security/login, but instead I'm seeing this page: http://173.7.8.9:8081/security/login.  I made up the ip address, but its the my assigned ip address from my network.

My security configuration looks like this:

```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers().permitAll()

            // All other requests are authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()

            .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/security/login");
   }
```

I thought this setup would work because I'm trying access the security/login path relative to the same server and port as the requested webpage.  The webpage is at http://localhost:8080/web/page, and the login page is at http://localhost:8080/security/login, same server and port but different paths.  But something in my setup is causing the actual server and port of the security login page to be substituted for the gateway server and port, and I need it to stop doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im assuming the configure method youve shown is for the security service ... What is the security configuration for the gateway ? The web app ? Can you show your routes ? When you hit 8080/web/page that would hit the gateway security configuration and then route to the web app, hitting that configuration ... I don't think the config youve provided would be involved.

Comment: I will throw an example together that demonstrates the issue.  I didn't think it would be necessary.  The portion of the security configuration that specifies "/security/login" I would expect to forward to localhost:8080/security/login and not to 173.7.8.9:8081/security/login.  I'll throw together a bare-bones demo and put it on github.

Comment: You can see an example here: https://github.com/scottellis64/micro

Comment: The README on that project describes the layout of the project, which is a little simpler than I've described above.  In the sample project, only the port number of the login page is wrong, and the only security configuration is that of the web application.  It should be easy enough to clone and try for yourself.  I'd really appreciate any insight that anyone could provide.  This is the last stumbling block to a large project that I proposing to move forward with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have it.  I updated my project to reflect the change.  The problem is that the security configuration (as James above I think is referring to) is in the web module.  I moved it to the gateway so that when forwarding to the login page, the port and server stay the same.  I can still forward to a login page in any module I choose, but the security configuration has to be applied to the gateway itself.

The latest version of my sample project works as intended now:  github.com/scottellis64/micro